# How to add serial number in django list?

Tags: django

I'm populating table using using for loop in django list view.

While populating I want to display serial number as well in the list.

```
{% for Attendee in filter.qs %} 
  {% if Attendee.checkin %}
    <tr>
      <td> Serial no. </td>
      <td>{{ Attendee.roll_no }}</td>
      <td>{{ Attendee.name }}</td>
      <td>{{ Attendee.branch }}</td>
    </tr>
    {% endif %}
```

As I'm using filter to display the results, it is not possible to maintain serial number in models.

I want something like this:

[image: img]

What are the other possible ways I can use to put serial numbers in list?

**EDIT:**

After using {{ forloop.counter }} in list, the serials aren't continuous.
eg:

[image]

Comment: What you mean by serial number? Just row count?

Comment: yes, just the row count.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want to do is use `{{forloop.counter}}`.  The problem is that the counter counts all iterations of the loop, not just ones where you do things.

The solution is to filter the list before passing it to the template.  For example:

```
context={"checked_in_attendees":  [i for i in filter.qs if i.checkin], ...}
```

Then, loop over `checked_in_attendees` on the template and `{{forloop.counter}}` will do what you want.

Answer (score 6):

You can access current iteration of the loop via `forloop.counter`(1-indexed) or `forloop.counter0`(0-indexed). For your case:

```
{% for Attendee in filter.qs %} 
    {% if Attendee.checkin %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ forloop.counter }}</td>
        <td>{{ Attendee.roll_no }}</td>
        <td>{{ Attendee.name }}</td>
        <td>{{ Attendee.branch }}</td>
    </tr>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Because of the fact that I am using django filter too, the list which I'm getting isn't serialized according to the filtered list. I've added the screenshot in the question.

Answer (score 2):

Django templates have own syntax in terms of get the index of the entity. Here I think you just need {{ forloop.counter }} for your serial number.